# Use Plugin Field inside buildForm()

Tags: entities, 8, media

In Drupal 8, I use this code inside my buildForm() method:

> ```
> $form['medias']['file'] = array(
>   '#title' => t('Image'),
>   '#type' => 'managed_file',
>   '#upload_location' => 'public://image_example_images/',
>   '#multiple' => true,
> );
> ```

(Bad) Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju0ZU.png

I would like know if it's possible to use [a plugin of type "field widget"](https://www.drupal.org/node/2064123) inside BuildForm() for call and use a field of Image type provided by the core of Drupal:

[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible?

Probably. But it would require a lot of work, as you would basically have to provide all the data and calls that such plugins need. That is very likely more work than re-implementing this functionality yourself.

And creating an entity type would only make sense if you need to manage multiple "things" that each has images attached.